# Recovery xfs partitions (after low space, i think)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos-7, partition-recovery, xfs

I don't really know the cause of that failure. I think, it caused by insufficient free space and hard reboot. 
So. We have Centos installed on the HyperV's virtual machine. File system is xfs. 
After hard reboot filesystem had a crash, and one partition dissapeared from the mapper, and system entered emergency mode. I found solution by making some changes in the fstab, but i still don't see one of my partitions in the mapper.

I can see partition and files via Active Partition Recovery software, and i'm able to save some files. But some of them, very important for me, are dissapeared. Unfortunately, as it comes every time, we don't have a backup.

I tried to use testdisk utility, but it said, that it seems that my disk should be bigger than it is.

Could some one help me to choose the way of thinking around the solution.
Should i try to recovery my files via recovery software?
Or should i try to recovery my partitions?

Help me, please.

Comment: I need to update my question. Partition is ok. I've lost logical volume.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok now )) It's just logical volume corrupt 
vgcfgrestore saved me

Here is the manual http://blackbird.si/restoring-deleted-logical-volume/